# How to create a Terraform module that extends/overrides another module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-modules

A Terraform module exposes a resource, with variables and outputs, for example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  function_name                      = var.function_name
  description                        = var.description
  runtime                            = var.runtime
  ...
```

I want to create a module that preconfigures the module above with a few key values, for example:

```
module "php_function" {
  source = "the/base/module"

  runtime       = "provided.al2"
}
```

But now the users of my module cannot set fields like `function_name` or `description` (they get `Unsupported argument`) because I didn't declare them as variables.

Is there a way to do this **without redefining all the variables, fields, and outputs in my module**?

I.e. ideally I just want to set my specific values, but users should be able to use all the variables & outputs the base module already provides.

Answer (score 1):

because 'aws_lambda_function' have some required attributes like functionname, discription etc. you cannot avoid it.

there is a workaround though, which I uses a lot.

1. Create a Variable with all the configurations for function(in your case)
2. Update the module and pass the values from the variable
3. Pass the values for the variable from the calling module

here is a quick example:

1. Variable holding the config

```
variable "function_config" {
 name = "xyz"
 descripton = "xyz"
 spsomeother = "xyz"
}
```

2. Variable definition in the module

```
variable "function_config" {
 name = string
 descripton = string
 spsomeother = string
}
```

3. Call the module and pass the values (here we have to declare the variable in  local for main.tf)

```
module "php_function" {
  source = "the/base/module"

  runtime       = "provided.al2".
  function_config = local.function_config
}
```

4. Update Module

```
locals{
 function_config = var.function_config
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  function_name                      = local.function_config.name
  description                        = local.function_config.description
  runtime                            = var.runtime
  ...
```